# Convert list of object to map of object

Tags: java, java-stream

How do I convert the following code below from list of objects to map of objects using Java stream?

```
List<OrderData> orderList = getOrderList();
Map<String, OrderData> orders = new HashMap<>();

orderList.forEach(order -> {
    OrderData orderData = orders.get(order.getOrderID());

    if (orderData == null || !order.getFiles().isEmpty()){
        orders.put(order.getOrderID(), order);
    }
});
```

Comment: `orderlist.stream().filter(...).collect(Collections.toMap(order -> order.getOrderID(), order -> order))`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Map<String, OrderData> collect = orderList.stream()
                .filter(o -> !o.getFiles().isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(OrderData::getOrderID,
                                          Function.identity()));
```

Comment: Mind the `orderData == null` condition. If it is intended duplicates may occur which would raise an `IllegalStateException` . Using `Map.computeIfAbsent` should handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

Collision processing is added based on `@f1sh`'s code:

```java
Map<String, OrderData> collect = orderList.stream()
        .filter(o -> !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(o.getOrderID()) && !o.getFiles().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(OrderData::getOrderID, Function.identity(), (k1, k2) -> k1));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).